# jquery radiogroup remove border aparat from selected

Tags: jquery

i have a radiogroup, in which i am selecting any one from the group. same time while i click on any radio button from the group, i am applying a border on the parent. so when i click on other radio button from the group, it should apply the border of clicked and need to remove the border from all other sibling parent... any good way to do this?

this is my code, but not works:

```
 $('input:radio[name="cci"]').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().css({border:'1px solid red'});//in the group, rest of the parent need to remove the border..how?
    })
```

meaning, while this is in selected position only the parent need to have the border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line

```
$('input:radio[name="cci"]').click(function(){
    $('input:radio[name="cci"]').css({border:'none'});
    $(this).parent().css({border:'1px solid red'});//in the group, rest of the parent need to remove the border..how?
    })
```

Comment: is it possible to do for all groups in single function?